Guidewire 10.2.3 Patch1 server is not starting
Getting below error while starting base OOTB code of this latest self managed version. Any suggestions on how to resolve it?
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 5: etc\C:\CM1023P1\modules\configuration\build\idea\webapp\WEB-INF\jetty.xml
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.FS.toPath(FS.java:158)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.BaseHome.getPath(BaseHome.java:237)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartArgs.resolveExtraXmls(StartArgs.java:1449)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
at com.guidewire.commons.jetty.GWServerJettyServerMain.main(GWServerJettyServerMain.java:62)
Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information
Process finished with exit code -9
Tried to remove .gradle folder and restart server. But it didn't work.

There are several cases when this error can occur. Here are a few most common scenarios that I have encountered.
1. Webresoures folder is missing from root directory
If you notice that the webresources folder is missing, it needs to be generated by calling gwb webResources from the command line. Please note that you also need the required version of node.js for this command to work on the latest on-prem or cloud versions. Most probably you will need nodejs v16.x.x. If you don't have it installed the above command will fail and give you the exact version number of nodejs required. Retry starting the Jetty server once you have webresources generated and it should work.
The webresources folder can also be generated from studio by clicking Tools -> Web Resources.
2. Remove any whitespaces in the path to your root directory.
Make sure to remove any whitespaces in your root Guidewire folder's path. e.g. If you have it in C:\Guidewire\Policy Center, just trim it to something like C:\Guidewire\PolicyCenter.
3. Remove whitespaces from IDEA_HOME directory
In case 1 and 2 didn't work, try removing the whitespaces from IDEA_HOME environment variable as well.
A combination of the above options always works for me and usually, it's Jetty server's inability to parse ":" in file paths that causes this issue.
